# How to provide a HWND to DirectSound SetCooperativeLevel in a console program?

Tags: windows, directsound

I'm writing a console program that uses DirectSound API to render some audio data. I stumbled on a curious problem when following the [DirectSound Programming Guide (from Microsoft)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee416964%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee416970%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) :

> After creating a device object, you must set the cooperative level for the device by using the [IDirectSound8::SetCooperativeLevel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.directx_sdk.idirectsound8.idirectsound8.setcooperativelevel%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) method. Unless you do this, no sounds will be heard.

The problem is that I'm writing a console program, and `SetCooperativeLevel` requires a HWND as a first argument. I don't have any HWND to deal with in the console program. I tried providing a null pointer but it failed with a `DSERR_INVALIDPARAM` error code.

What HWND value should be provided to `IDirectSound8::SetCooperativeLevel` in a console program ? The audio part of the program is planned to be built as a shared library, so it has little to no knowledge of the "outside" program.

Thanks for any advice !

*Note : I know that there is a somewhat better solution for simply rendering audio, like using SDL, OpenAL, SFML (based on OpenAL), but for my current project DirectSound is enforced.*

---

**Edit** : I found a [message](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.directx.audio/msg/2145cdcf7753c9c3) from a Microsoft engineer that removes doubts about using the desktop window or the console window as a HWND for `SetCooperativeLevel` when creating GLOBAL_FOCUS buffers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I have not tested this myself, you may have some success creating a hidden window and passing its HWND to the `SetCooperativeLevel` method. `SetCooperativeLevel` uses this hwnd to determine when your application has input focus; therefore, if you select a cooperative level where the input focus doesn't matter (eg, `DSSCL_NORMAL`), a hidden window (which will never receive input focus) *should* be fine.

Comment: As you said, the input focus should not interfere when rendering audio. I innocently tested providing the HWND returned by `GetDesktopWindow()` to `SetCooperativeLevel`, and it seems to work. However, I don't know if it has any drawbacks compared to using a hidden window handle ...

Comment: Passing a HWND you don't control seems like a very bad idea. It's one of those things that'll probably work just fine - until the day your code ends up being dissected at dailywtf or "the old new thing".

Comment: @overcoder, I'd be worried about what happens if another program decides to do the same thing...

Comment: @snemarch, @bdonlan : You're right. I prefer writing it properly, as described by bdonlan. Murphy's law come to mind : 'Anything that can possibly go wrong, does' ...

Comment: It's perfectly fine to pass another app's HWND to DirectSound.  Not a great design, but it works.  This is how certain gamer voice-comm app's like RogerWilco and Battlecom used to do it before DSSCL_EXCLUSIVE mode was deprecated (and all the games used that mode).  The game could remain in the foreground with it's own HWND, yet the voice-comm app could play audio in the background.  As a matter of fact, you don't even have to pass in a valid HWND at all if you're using coop mode that doesn't care about app focus.  You could pass in anything non-zero.

Comment: @selbie : Thanks for your reply. I previously found that using some nonzero HWND works fine, but the doubt is still present without an explicit reference or documentation. I (heavily) googled to find one from a microsoft engineer : http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.directx.audio/msg/2145cdcf7753c9c3

Answer (score 2):

you can use this `::GetDesktopWindow()`.